# Img src URL not working for images from instagram "/?__a=1"

Tags: html, json, web-scraping, instagram

I'm trying to get the **profile_pic_url**s from instagram's "*/?__a=1*" profiles.

When I put them inside a  `<img src="">`  it doesn't work.
It actually does not work for any image url in the json.

Is it a limitation of facebook? Is there a way to edit the url to make it work?

Take the profile_pic_url from https://www.instagram.com/zuck/?__a=1 as an example:

```html
<img src="https://instagram.fmxp10-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/177219615_1728341124004802_3178671336629535217_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fmxp10-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_ohc=0jrm53_8VuMAX8Wdh4I&edm=AAWvnRQBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=0ffa1ac452bacb959adab6ace79283cb&oe=616FB4A3&_nc_sid=e7738c">
```

Comment: Open console and you will see that it's CORS restriction. Use instagram API instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive that Instagram stops user form using image links
my alternate option is that you use imgur or onedrive
this will make it so u can use links

OneDrive(microsoft):https://onedrive.live.com/
Imgur:https://imgur.com/
Have a great Day/Night!

Answer (score 1):

I can think of three solutions:

1. you use the API as Mr.justinas says
2. you can save the pictures locally
3. or you can use the embed code that they provide go to the picutre you want click on the three dots then embed and copy it

[Refrence](https://cavesocial.com/embed-instagram-photo-website-blog/)